# How can I embedding apple's demo: Capturing Body Motion in 3D in my swiftui App?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, arkit

It is my first time to use swiftui, so I’m not very clear that how to use the [demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) in my swiftui App. I find the demo is based on UIKIT, but my App is based on swiftui, so I don't know how to adapt the demo to the App. I have tried to wrap the HumanViewController as follow:

```
struct HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = HumanViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper>) -> HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainViewController: HumanViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main1") as! HumanViewController
      return mainViewController

    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper>) {
        //
    }
}
```

All my code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  random name
//
//  
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           NavigationLink("click here", destination: HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = HumanViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper>) -> HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainViewController: HumanViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main1") as! HumanViewController
      return mainViewController

    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HumanViewControllerControllerWrapper>) {
        //
    }
}
```

```
//
//  HumanViewController.swift
//  random name
//
//

import Foundation
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
The sample app's main view controller.
*/

import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import Combine

public class HumanViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    // The 3D character to display.
    var character: BodyTrackedEntity?
    let characterOffset: SIMD3<Float> = [-1.0, 0, 0] // Offset the character by one meter to the left
    let characterAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        
        // If the iOS device doesn't support body tracking, raise a developer error for
        // this unhandled case.
        guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
            fatalError("This feature is only supported on devices with an A12 chip")
        }

        // Run a body tracking configration.
        let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.session.delegate = self
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        
        arView.scene.addAnchor(characterAnchor)
        
        // Asynchronously load the 3D character.
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
        cancellable = Entity.loadBodyTrackedAsync(named: "character/robot").sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                    print("Error: Unable to load model: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                cancellable?.cancel()
        }, receiveValue: { (character: Entity) in
            if let character = character as? BodyTrackedEntity {
                // Scale the character to human size
                character.scale = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
                self.character = character
                cancellable?.cancel()
            } else {
                print("Error: Unable to load model as BodyTrackedEntity")
            }
        })
    }
    
    public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        for anchor in anchors {
            guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }
            
            // Update the position of the character anchor's position.
            let bodyPosition = simd_make_float3(bodyAnchor.transform.columns.3)
            characterAnchor.position = bodyPosition + characterOffset
            // Also copy over the rotation of the body anchor, because the skeleton's pose
            // in the world is relative to the body anchor's rotation.
            characterAnchor.orientation = Transform(matrix: bodyAnchor.transform).rotation
   
            if let character = character, character.parent == nil {
                // Attach the character to its anchor as soon as
                // 1. the body anchor was detected and
                // 2. the character was loaded.
                characterAnchor.addChild(character)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//
//  random_nameApp.swift
//  random name
//
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct random_nameApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        //add code when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        return true
    }
}
```

And it failed when I click the link on my device. The log is:

```
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file random_name/HumanViewController.swift, line 42
```

So how can I deal with the bug or anyone can tell me how to embed the demo in my App?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line, in the code you've posted, does the error occur on?

Comment: If I had to guess I suspect the `arView` outlet in your controller is not set properly in Interface Builder.

Comment: Hi, it occurs on HumanViewController.swift, the sentence "arView.session.delegate = self",  because it think arview is nil, so it can't move on.

Comment: `arView` is nil because you haven't assigned it.  It is listed as an `@IBOutlet`.  Do you know what that means?

Comment: I have searched the document, but I can't understand it clearly, shall I load a view for it?

Comment: Please go through this documentation. I hope it will help you https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit